# Starting Cassandra in Shell script

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to write code in shell script that starts Cassandra on my local machine. Any advice or documentation I can refer to? I am new to using shell script and most of what I have found online about starting Cassandra on shell script has been about starting Cassandra in your terminal and not which shell script command to use to start Cassandra when you already have it on your machine.

So the question is: what shell script command would you use to start a Cassandra cluster locally?

Answer (score 0):

- To start Cassandra, open the terminal window, navigate to Cassandra home directory/home, where you unpacked Cassandra, and run the following command to start your Cassandra server.

  $ cd $CASSANDRA_HOME
  $ ./bin/cassandra -f
- Starting Cassandra as a service

  $ systemctl start cassandra

Answer (score 0):

Starting a local Cassandra instance depends on the installation type.

If you've installed Cassandra as a YUM (RHEL/CentOS) or APT (Debian) package, start the service with:

```
$ sudo service cassandra start
```

If you've installed Cassandra using the binary tarball, you start it with:

```
$ cd /path/to/tarball/installation
$ bin/cassandra
```

For more details, see [Installing Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html). Cheers!